# What does "IR" mean in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I am new to linear algebra and I was wondering if I could get some help for this question. I  understand if it was something like this IR^2 -> IR. I have no idea what IR(=IR^1) means. Could someone please explain?

(MathJax version: $\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$)

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$, the real numbers.

Comment: @vadim123 so you're saying IR (=IR^1) is the real numbers? Is that just another way of writing IR?

Comment: @user179531 Yeah

Comment: Note that it's a single letter `R`, not a pair of letters `I` and `R`. I can understand why you read it as `IR`, but that's an incorrect way to read the symbol.

Comment: In rather ancient times, it was quite common to use `{\bf I\!R}` (plain TeX notation) for denoting the real numbers: $\bf I\!R$. Then AMS issued the blackboard bold font…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}$, written as \mathbb{R} in MathJax, is the letter R in the special font "blackboard bold".  Traditionally, several letters in this font have special meanings:

$\mathbb{R}$ real numbers
$\mathbb{Z}$ integers
$\mathbb{N}$ natural numbers 
$\mathbb{Q}$ rational numbers (fractions) 
$\mathbb{C}$ complex numbers

Comment: Is there a name for this sort of notation (instead of special letters or whatever)?

Comment: ["blackboard bold"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold). The double line is supposed to resemble a thick line, drawn with a the side of a chalk on a blackboard. I've never seen anyone do that in practice though.