# What's does $\mathbb{R}^n$ in linear algebra represent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering if someone could briefly add to my understanding of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in linear algebra.

From what I understand if its $\mathbb{R}^2$ it's 2 sets of $x$, $y$ values, where as $\mathbb{R}^3$ wold be 3 sets of $x$, $y$, $z$ values.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950397/what-does-ir-mean-in-linear-algebra?rq=1

Comment: Do you mean $IR^n$ or $\mathbb R^n$ ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - $IR^n$ is a thing? What's the $I$ for? I've never seen that before

Comment: Is it possible you just mean what you might write on the blackboard as |R^n? That is the vectors with $n$ real components.

Comment: All right thanks Ian. With your comment just explained it. So if it was |P^n would that than be all polynominals with in that degree with n real components?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}^n = \{(a_1, \dots, a_n) : a_i \in \mathbb{R}, \forall i \in \{1, \dots, n\}\}$